# Linear representation of finite group.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and $K=\mathbb C$ a field. I have to give the non equivalent $K-$ linear representation of degree 1. I can do it, but I wanted to know something:

I know that to have a linear representation is equivalent than to have a $KG-$module where $KG$ is the group ring of $G$. How can I get a $KG-$module here ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking, but here we go:

**Answer:** If you have a $G$-module $V$, then you get a $KG$-module by extending the action linearly: $$\left(\sum_g\alpha_gg\right).v=\sum_g\alpha_g(g.v)$$

Note that having a $G$-module is the same as having an action of $G$ on a vector space by linear transformations. In order to turn this into an action of the ring $KG$, you additionally need $$(\lambda g+\mu h).v=\lambda(g.v)+\mu(h.v),\;\;\;\lambda,\mu\in K,\;g,h\in G,\;v\in V,$$ which is precisely what "extending the action linearly" does.

By the way, I prefer to work with the multipicative group $C_2\times C_2$ so I don't have any confusion regarding addition in $K$ vs. addition in $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ (which can be awkward).